# Reuse Node.js flow type definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

I'm working on a small wrapper around Node.js child_process module, and I would like to reuse some flow type definitions.

For example I would like to create the following function in my code :

```
function execp (command: string, options?: child_process$execOpts)
```

The `child_process$execOpts` type is defined here : https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.57.3/lib/node.js#L122

Tried different imports way but I'm not very advanced with Flow and I think this might be some kind of private type so it cannot be imported in my code. But if that is the case that's a bummer, don't want to copy/paste the typedef or use `any` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `child_process$execOpts` type isn't exported, so I'm afraid you need to declare (copy/paste) it yourself for your own code.